# While Loop Variable Initialization and Variable Types(C)

Tags: c, loops, variables

I'm relatively new to coding and am currently studying C. I had some trouble regarding a textbook exercise and some help would be much appreciated.

The exercise's main objective is to calculate the total salary that an employee should receive by inputting the hours of work done and the hourly rate. The rate is 100% up to 40 hours, but after 40 hours it goes up to 150%. Here's the code that I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int employee, hour, ratenormal, totalrate, counter, rate;
    int salary;

    hour = 1;

    while (hour != -1) {
        printf("Enter # of hours worked (-1 to end): ");
        scanf_s("%d", &hour);
        if (hour == -1) break;

        printf("Enter hourly rate of the work ($00.00): $");
        scanf_s("%d", &rate);

        if (hour <= 40) {
            salary = hour * rate;
        }
        else if (hour > 40) {
            salary = salary + ((hour - 40) * (rate * 1.5));
        }

        printf("Salary is $%d\n\n", salary);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I had a couple of questions:

1) If I declare the variable "salary" as a float, then the result only prints 0. Why is that?

2) The loop works fine, but only for the first iteration. The problem is that I need to initialize the variable salary again, otherwise it keeps storing some of the value that has been previously used. How could I do this?

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is using `salary` **uninitialized** in the `salary` calculation for hours > 40. You can take from that it is always good to initialize your variables. Next, you should simply substitute `40 * rate` for normal rate part of `salary` in the hour > 40 salary equation, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int hour = 0;
    float rate = 0.0, salary = 0.0;

    while (hour != -1) {
        printf("Enter # of hours worked (-1 to end): ");
        if (scanf ("%d", &hour) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid hours input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (hour == -1) break;

        printf("Enter hourly rate of the work ($00.00): $");
        if (scanf ("%f", &rate) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid rate input.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (hour <= 40) {
            salary = hour * rate;
        }
        else if (hour > 40) {
            salary = 40 * rate + ((hour - 40) * (rate * 1.5));
        }

        printf("Salary is $%.2f\n\n", salary);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/salary2
Enter # of hours worked (-1 to end): 20
Enter hourly rate of the work ($00.00): $10.50
Salary is $210.00

Enter # of hours worked (-1 to end): 60
Enter hourly rate of the work ($00.00): $10.50
Salary is $735.00
```

**note:** I have no `scanf_s` function on Linux (they `_s` flavors a primarily windoze), so I have used `scanf` above, but `scanf_s` will work fine in  your case.

Answer (score 0):

end of the line `printf("Salary is $%d\n\n", salary);` declare `salary = 0;` Otherwise else condition don't work properly you get previous value also.

Answer (score 0):

To answer 1). Declare salary as a float and then print it like so

```
printf("Salary is $%.2f\n\n", salary);
```

the format %.2f will print the float as with 2 decimals. So if the salary was 550.5 it would print 
**Salary is $550.50**

If I understood question 2) properly I think you want to do this to calculate the salary

```
    salary = hour * rate;
    if (hour > 40) {
        salary = salary + ((hour - 40) * (rate * 1.5));
    }
```

With your code, if you enter a number of hours greater than 40 after the first iteration you will reuse the salary value of the previous iteration. In all cases you always want to re calculate the salary value with the standard rate, then IF the number of hours is greater than 40 you add to the salary the number additional hours multiplied by the overtime rate

Answer (score 0):

If you are using salary as float then you have to print

```
printf("Salary is $%f\n\n", salary);
salary=0.0;
```